# Is there a design pattern to write a dispatcher logic that calls specific methods based on given path?

Tags: java, design-patterns

We have a use case where we need to write a dispatcher class that takes the rest request object and should call the specific methods based on the request. For example we have a class `Users` that has methods to get, put, delete and post user data. We have another class `Ledger` that has methods related to ledgers add money, send money, create, delete etc. The dispatcher should take the request object and if the path is `/users/*` it should call the specific method in `Users` class. If the path is `/ledger/*` it should call the specific method in `Ledger` class. Is there a design pattern for such use cases?

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario you should use facade design pattern and provide a wrapper interface on top of the existing interface to help client application.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine factory and strategy pattern.
you can create a class for each scenario and a factory class or method to decide which class should initialize..also you can create a facade class to hide implemention complexity.